# Value replacement in Pandas and Object Destruction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas.

Here is my problem: I have a column corrupted in an excel file that I want to change for reading purposes, I have checked and the conditions are working fine and the values are being replaced in the for loop but it is not being carried out of it so when i open the new file the values are the same as before

```
import pandas

my_data = pandas.read_excel("actualizar sp_py.xlsx")

 for row in my_data.loc[:,"Estado Jira"]:
     if row == "En anÃ¡lisis":
         row = "En Analisis"
     elif row == "Pte AceptaciÃ³n Operador":
         row = "Pte Aceptacion Operador"
     elif row == "Pendiente de DocumentaciÃ³n":
         row = "Pendiente de Documentacion"
     elif row == "Pte. recepciÃ³n oferta":
         row = "Pte recepcion de Oferta"
     elif row == "Pte instalaciÃ³n":
         row = "Pte instalacion"

my_data.to_excel("my_new_file.xlsx")
```

I have trouble understanding why the values in the Series are not being properly replaced. I am guessing the object created in the loop is somehow destroyed but I am not experienced in python enough yet.

Comment: You are assigning the name row to a value from the column and then changing it according to various conditions. But you are then not doing anything with it. It is not automatically put back into the column as you are assuming. This is an important point you should grasp. In any case, the link provided in the closure notice is a much better way to do what you want.